# XCode - nested functions are disabled !

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nested-function

I used to be able to do forEach loops in XCode, but after installing sdk 4 i get errors

**error: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable**

How can i enable nested functions
It says "use -fnested-", but use is where? how?

```
for (MyObject *obj : array)
{

}
```

Comment: Wait... wot? Can you post the exact snippet of code that was causing the problem?  Or try compiling with Clang and make sure the error message is reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
for (MyObject * obj in array) { ... }
```

(Note that you use `in` and not `:`.